# Query for current post

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, meta-query

I want to show current post.I will use this query in single template for custom post type.When click the custom post type, only the post will shown.

How can I write this query?

In wordpress developer page, $post exists as a query arg.But there is no how to use $post arg.

I write this : $post=get_post(); but it didnt work.How can I write $post as a arg in query array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be writing any query. WordPress does this for you. You `single-{post type}.php` template should only contain the [standard loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#the-loop-in-detail):

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        // Display post content
    endwhile; 
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: One plugin's shortcode with php command doesnt work in single-html5blank.php while it works on posts and pages.Can I fix it for my theme? What kind of thing cause this if there is no command to avoid this in plugin?

Comment: I added content function then it works now.Thank you also your answer